# Why do I use "parse"

Tags: vb.net

What is the reasoning for parsing an integer? For instance, `Integer.Parse('variable'.text)`

I see this a lot and while manipulating data for a calculator I am building I found that `Val('variable'.text)` was all I need to use "numeric" values.

So, my question is how does `Integer.Parse()` help me with regards to calculators?

Thanks!

Comment: When the user inputs text, it is accepted as a string. You can't perform mathematical operations on strings, so you need to parse them to integers. `Val` is just a method that parses a `String` to a `Double`.

Comment: `val` always and forever returns a Double.  If you want/need a Decimal or Integer, use the appropriate Parse.  I suspect `Option Strict` is also worth a mention at this point: use it always.

Comment: Plutonix - I guess my only problem was on my Window Form the text box variable I was using kept throwing an exception about conversion to integer/decimal. Didn't matter what I used. I thought maybe it was useful in another manner. However, I feel I am just coding it wrong. I will work at using parse for my calculator. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind users can type in all sorts of nonsense in a textbox.  A quantity input might contain "I Like Pie"  what is the value of that?  `Val` will report 0, Integer.TryParse will report False telling you it is not a valid value.

Answer (score 5):

> I found that "Val('variable'.text)" was all I need

If that's the case then go ahead and use `Val()`.  But be aware that [it behaves differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) than `.Parse()` (or, often preferably, `.TryParse()`) methods.

For example, what do you want to do if the user inputs `"123 isn't 456"`?  `Val()` will (I think) return:

```
123 As Double
```

Or how about the input `"123 456"`?  That would be:

```
123456 As Double
```

Do you want it to be a `Double`?  Do you want it to throw an error because it's not purely numeric?  Something else?  The behavior you want should be reflected in the code you write.  Use `Val()` for one set of behaviors, `.Parse()` for another.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I had some issues getting my "form control" text/rich textbox to allow parsing within my code. However, now reading over what you wrote... I think I should figure out how to use parse. Thanks so much!